# Unable to re-use existing BCrypted passwords when registering/importing legacy users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt, fusionauth

When trying to register users with FusionAuth which do already have an Bcrypted password, which was originally generated with `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt` (with 10 hashing rounds) the user is not able to use her password when trying to authenticate with FusionAuth any longer.

The hashed passwords look like:
`$2a$10$3sTYd6sHbHIsTO2jBiishOTmcvFS.bJ2X2lbIDO1w2o4MNXXXXXXX`

The import code (in Kotlin) looks like:

```
val response = client.register(null, RegistrationRequest(User().apply {
                username = user.username
                email = user.email
                firstName = user.firstname
                lastName = user.lastname
                active = user.isActive
                encryptionScheme = "bcrypt"
                password = user.password // generated with BCrypt(10) 
                passwordChangeRequired = false
                data.putAll(mapOf(
                        "mainMandant" to user.mainMandant?.mandantName,
                        "custodianMandants" to user.custodianMandants.joinToString { it.mandantName },
                        "technicalUser" to user.isTechnicalUser
                ))
            }, UserRegistration().apply {
                applicationId = myAppId
                roles = extractUserRoles(user).toSortedSet()
                preferredLanguages.add(Locale.GERMAN)
                username = user.username
            }, false, true))
```

With FusionAuth system settings "Cryptographic hash settings" is configured to use Scheme "Salted Bcrypt" with Factor 10 and re-hash on login enabled.

How to register an user and allow to re-use the existing password if possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Registration API does not accept a hashed password, this API will assume the value provided in the `password` field is plain text.

In order to import a user with an existing hashed password, you will need to use the Import API. 
https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#import-users

Once you import the user, if you enable the `re-hash at login` the password hash will be update to match the configured values in the system configuration at next login.